# Get immediate child using nextUntil

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html :)

```
<div class="categories">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="root list-group-item" id="427" style="display: block;"><span class="glyphicon indent0 glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><span>Home</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item first active" id="428" style="display: block;"><span class="glyphicon indent1 glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span>Images</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item child" id="431" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right indent2"></span><span>Sub category</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item child" id="433" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon indent3"></span><span>Super sub</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item first" id="429" style="display: block;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right indent1"></span><span>Videos</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item child" id="432" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon indent2"></span><span>Another sub</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item first" id="430" style="display: block;"><span class="glyphicon indent1"></span><span>Documents</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have this function:

```
$(".glyphicon", treeRoot).on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $glyph = $(this);
    var $item = $glyph.parent();
    var indent = $item.find(".glyphicon").prop('className').match(/\b(indent\d+)\b/)[1];

    if (indent != undefined) {
        var $children = $item.nextUntil("a:has(." + indent + ")");

        if ($glyph.hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-right")) {
            $glyph
                .addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down')
                .removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");

            if ($children != null) $children.show();
        } else {
            $glyph
                .addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')
                .removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");

            if ($children != null) $children.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

So basically, when the icon is clicked, it shows or hides the children.
The problem is, it shows all children (indent2 and indent3) but I just want it to show the immediate children (indent2 in this example).

Could someone give me some insight on how to do this?

Cheers,

/r3plica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var num = parseInt(indent.match(/(\d+)$/)[1], 10);
var $children = $item.nextUntil("a:not(:has(.indent" + (num + 1) + "))");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5C5Kf/)

Comment: Hi Arun, I found an issue with this statement. It doesn't get all the same level children :( I have updated my question. If you could help that would be great